# Does the Chromium project use a file management library?

Tags: c++, file-io, v8, chromium

Does the Chromium project use a cross-platform file management library that:

- Copies files
- move files
- deletes files

If so, which library?

Comment: What's this got to do with V8?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes I want to make sure that I pick a library that isn't going to conflict. V8 is incredibly complex. I will alter the wording of my question

Comment: V8 is a Javascript engine, and yet you mention C++. Are you looking to extend the engine, or are you looking for a Javascript library that will run on top on V8?

Comment: @Sean I am using the V8 source library to execute JavaScript in a custom application. I have that much working, but I would like to be able to enable certain file routines within JavaScript using a global object that I have defined called `console` (ie. `console.copyFile(from, to)`, `console.moveFile(from, to)`) I would like to be able to use wildcards to copy and entire directory...but in C++ there seem to be problems with cross-platform creation of direction, etc. so I suspect that chromium uses a library to achieve this but I am not sure

Comment: @Sean is the Boost Filesystem library likely to work with this? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I'm not familiar with the Chromium source code you should find, as mentioned in the comments, that the [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library gives you what you're asking for.